# How do I get HexChat to start on i3 login in its own workspace (but not in workspace 1)?

Tags: i3, autostart

On i3 start up I'd like HexChat to automatically start in my fifth workspace.

I know how to edit my config (`~/.i3/config`) to start HexChat on i3 start up, namely by adding `exec hexchat` line to it, but that starts it in my first workspace, when I want it started in my fifth workspace (i.e. `$workspace5` in my i3 config). Despite this, I want workspace 1 to be the one I'm shown on i3 start up (which is what I'm shown with my current config).

My i3 configs are [here](https://github.com/fusion809/i3-configs/tree/opensuse) and my distribution is openSUSE Tumbleweed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find some [criteria](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#command_criteria) that matches your window, then you can configure a workspace for it.  I don't know HexChat, so here is an example for `xclock`. If you run this well-know X11 application, then run `xprop` and click on the clock window you will get output showing you the window class is `XClock`:

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "xclock", "XClock"
```

So in your config you would have

```
assign [class="^XClock$"] 5
exec --no-startup-id xclock
```

This matches the class with a regular expression, hence the `^` and `$`, but in most cases you can be less explicit.

Comment: Is there a way to get multiple apps to open in multiple different workspaces on start up? This allows HexChat to start in its own workspace, but if I add a few extra apps (with both lines of code you shared copied and tailored to the app, including the `class` line) that are meant to open each in their own workspace, I end up with a situation wherein they all, except for HexChat, open in workspace 1. Here's my updated config file -- https://gist.github.com/08b58520ebccec21d18cb4f7bf9a78ac.

Comment: You need to be careful with the class names, as i3 only uses the 2nd string from the WM_CLASS X11 property, so your assigns are not matching. For example, for xterm it is `XTerm`.

Comment: Your methods have really improved my i3 experience mate, tyvm for it. I honestly thought this question would receive no answers, but luckily you found this question and provided a first-class answer. :)